# How to make Alt+delete delete word in Mac Powerpoint?

Tags: macos, applications, ms-office

Unlike just about every other Mac Program, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> does not delete the preceding word in Mac Powerpoint 2011. I find this unnecessary inconsistency very annoying.

Is there any way of making <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> delete a word in Mac Powerpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using KeyRemap4MacBook, you could add this to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<item>
<name>Powerpoint</name>
<identifier>private.powerpoint</identifier>
<only>POWERPOINT</only>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::DELETE, VK_OPTION, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::DELETE</autogen>
</item>
```

Further details:

1. Open KeyRemap4MacBook - Mis & Uninstall - Open private.xml
2. Edit `private.xml` and Add the above snippet between `<root>` and `</root>`
3. Go to the `change key` tab in the KeyRemap4MacBook and press `ReloadXML`
4. Then select the "Powerpoint" box under `remapping`

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish this without an extra app? For example with AppleScript?